# Delete key/value pairs of multiple JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array with multiple JSON objects. I don't need all key/values in my file so I want to delete e.g. all "Completed" keys and their values across all of those JSON objects. 
I know I could delete specific key/value pairs with the `delete` operator though leaving `undefined` holes in the array. I don't want that because I think it will cause problems later on when I work with the array.

I also tried it with splice:

```
data.splice(data[i].Completed, data.length);
```

Did I make a mistake with splice?

Acutally I want to create a new **file** without certain key/values. In my approaches I just manipulated the existing file without creating a new one … how could I do that?

```
var data = [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Titel": "ui sketch",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Titel": "coding",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 4,
    "Importance": 4
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Titel": "meeting",
    "Completed": "no",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
]
```

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) objects? really strings?

Comment: please add what youi want, the same array with deleted objects, or just a new array without completed items?

Comment: `splice` would be for removing array data, not key/value in your objects. If you only want to remove the `"Completed": "yes"` key/value, and not the entire object containing that value, `splice` wouldn't do the trick.

Comment: I want the same array with deleted key/value pairs e.g. "Completed":"yes" and "Completed":"no". But I want to also do this with more complex key/value pairs that differ a lot from each other in each object e.g. "latitude":"123.23324.21", "longitutde":"3432.23242.31"

Comment: @Randy what would do the trick then? When I try it with map() the browser doesn't load the file ... Could this be due to my 200.000 objects in the array? Is that just to much for map()?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove all objects with key 'Completed' equals 'yes' you do:

```
const newData = data.filter(el => el.Completed !== 'yes')
```

If you need to remove all keys Completed in case they are equal to 'yes', you do:

```
const newData = data.map(el => {
  if (el.Completed === 'yes') delete el.Completed
  return el;
})
```

In most common case for objects you use delete and for Arrays you use splice.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want to delete all `Completed` properties from the objects in the `data` array.

In that case, you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make a new array with objects that have the properties you want:

```js
var data = [{"ID": 1,"Titel": "ui sketch","Completed": "yes","Prio": 3,"Importance": 2},{"ID": 2,"Titel": "coding","Completed": "yes","Prio": 4,"Importance": 4},{"ID": 5,"Titel": "meeting","Completed": "no","Prio": 3,"Importance": 2}],
    result = data.map(elem => {
      return {
        ID: elem.ID,
        Titel: elem.Titel,
        Prio: elem.Prio,
        Importance: elem.Importance
      };
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Yosvel. Your solution works on my given example. Unfortunately  it doesn't seem to work on very large datasets. +50mb … The browser is unable to load the file …

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` methods: [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter%20Documentation%20on%20MDN).

Here what it looks like:

```js
var data = [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Titel": "ui sketch",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Titel": "coding",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 4,
    "Importance": 4
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Titel": "meeting",
    "Completed": "no",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
]

// New array from former one.
var undone = data.filter(obj => obj["Completed"] != "yes");

// Skim data from completed elements
data = data.filter(obj => obj["Completed"] != "yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Titel": "ui sketch",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Titel": "coding",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 4,
    "Importance": 4
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Titel": "meeting",
    "Completed": "no",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
]

var i =data.length-1;
for(i ; i>= 0;i--){
    if(data[i].Completed == "yes"){
        data.splice( i, 1 );
    }
}
alert(data[0].Titel);
```

here you have it, search for completed == "yes" , if so , splice it, you end up with an array with 1 element :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var data = [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Titel": "ui sketch",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Titel": "coding",
    "Completed": "yes",
    "Prio": 4,
    "Importance": 4
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Titel": "meeting",
    "Completed": "no",
    "Prio": 3,
    "Importance": 2
  }
];

var data = data.map(item => { 
  return {
    "ID": item.ID,
    "Titel": item.Titel,
    "Prio": item.Prio,
    "Importance": item.Importance
  }
});

console.log(data);
```